# "practices" vs. "acts"

Tags: meaning

From Cambridge

> [act](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/act)
>
> something that you do
>
> [practice](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/practice?q=PRACTICES)
>
> something that is usually or regularly done, often as a habit, tradition, or custom

[From a post](https://www.cfpaguide.com/portalresource/Exam%20Manual%20v%202%20-%20UDAAP.pdf)

> Unfair, deceptive, or abusive **acts and practices** (UDAAPs) can cause significant financial injury to
>   consumers, erode consumer confidence, and undermine the financial marketplace

[From another post](https://ustr.gov/sites/default/files/Section%20301%20FINAL.PDF)

> FINDINGS OF THE INVESTIGATION INTO
>   CHINA’S **ACTS, POLICIES, AND PRACTICES**

Both of them seem to indicate that 'acts' and 'practices' have different meanings. One of the differences is whether that "thing" takes place **regularly**. Is my understanding right?

Could someone give an act that is not a practice and a practice that is not an act?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An unsanctioned "act" would be when, as a one-off, a vendor sells a shoddy article in order to clear it off the shelf, and refuse to refund it when the customer complains it is not up to standard.

An unsanctioned "practice" would be when a company, for example, manufactures a forgery of an authentic commodity and sells it as if it were the genuine article.

An "act" as described above could then *become* a "practice" if it were what the vendor did as a general technique for shifting otherwise unsaleable product -- but if it remains a one-off then it is an *act*.

Comment: Thank you. Does "article" refer to something like a research paper or a post on a website?

Comment: I use the word "article" merely to mean "physical thing" in the context of a "commodity". The word has a far wider usage than just "published piece of work". In this context it could mean, for example, to pull out of my head something completely at random, "kettle".